# Прямая(,) парралельная двум прямым некой плоскости(,) парралельна этой плоскости

Tags: запятые

Нужны запятые?

> Все знают, что кот(,) полосатый по-чёрно-белому(,) лучше кота(,) полосатого по-жёлто-чёрному.

> Прямая(,) парралельная двум прямым некой плоскости(,) парралельна этой плоскости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Нужны запятые:**

*ПрямАя, **параллельная двум прямым некой плОскости**, параллельна этой плоскости.*

Про котов аналогично.

Определительный оборот **обособляется**: ударение делается на существительном и на обороте.

Можно заменить: *ПрямАя, **которая параллельна двум прямым некой плОскости**, параллельна этой плоскости.*

Comment: То есть пунктуация от интонации зависит, когда речь идёт о прилагательных?

Comment: Не совсем так.  Здесь зависимость от смысла. Нужно дать определение для прямой, поэтому существительное выделено ударением. Кроме того, распространенность оборота имеет значение. Прямая параллЕльная ему... здесь ударение можно перенести на оборот.